# Do I remove java 12 the same way(s) I do other versions?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, java, uninstall

Two questions.

**Can I safely simply remove a tar.gz file for java that I found?**

**What are the steps to remove java 12 and install java 8 on ubuntu 16.04?**

If this has been asked and answered before, I apologize. Please provide instructions or a link at least for removing 12. Sources that have copy/paste commands are best, since I don't have background knowledge that programmers have to fill in blanks. I'm just retail.

I forget exactly what I've tried. Normally things work eventually, but I've been at this for days. I've been to so many web pages I can't remember where I've found information. Some pages are as old as 10 years. Many are for earlier versions of ubuntu. Some provide commands to install/remove openjdk and others are just jdk.

**1)** 16.04 has been working for me for a couple years, apparently with java 8. Recently it suggested that 18.04 was available, and I finally got that installed. But too many things didn't work the same, and I **reinstalled 16.04** from scratch from a USB stick.

**2)** After that, one app that I use every day was giving me an error message *Every Time* I brought it up. Never happened before. I thought that **upgrading java to version 12** might help/couldn't hurt.

I forget the exact steps used to **remove java 8** and don't want to hunt for it again. I remember the command included something like "8.0_222". Somehow I found that there are still a lot of files that reference "8.0_221" as below.

[image: 80221]

**Can I just delete the *tar.gz file at the bottom?**

At any rate, I finally got no output for 'java -version'.

**3)** When I went to **install java 12**, one of the procedures resulted in a DOS-type box that wanted me to accept oracle's license. But it didn't respond -- at all -- to the keyboard or mouse. I had to close other apps and shut the machine down. That happened a couple times, including the box. One of those times I saw the box change from OK to yes/no -- just as it disappeared and I don't know what input it got. I suppose I said Yes and it ran in the background (no output in the terminal window), because later I was trying other commands and all of a sudden it said that version 12 was installed! No idea how that happened, but **my current tests (from various sources) have the following output. So I think now I only have 12 on the system.**

[image: output]

**4)** Now my app says that it needs java 8 or later just to install. So I need to go back to version 8. Some pages indicate that you can have multiple versions on the machine, you set a default version and you can switch. I don't know how that works. Life with 16.04 was fine before all this, so I think to remove 12 and reinstall 8. But I can't find instructions that I'm comfortable with to remove 12.

There are so many sources. The last bullet point on [this one from Oracle](https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_uninstall.xml) (I've never used rpm to install anything) says to just remove a directory. That's it? It refers to version 1.7 and the current version is 12? Here is a directory I found. The name format is different from any other examples I've seen.

[image]

I think I saw a reference to an openjdk for version 12, which I think is all I need. But what I see on my system doesn't start with "open", as numerous pages specify.

What do I do, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default java on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985521/default-java-on-ubuntu) and [Install Java version 8 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1068347/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Java version 8 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068347/install-java-version-8-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Yes you can delete that tar.gz file if you want. You likely got it from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jre8-downloads.html) and can get it again if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments (THANK YOU), I used the commands below, in this order. I didn't do any of the other steps specified in the links.

I don't know what leaving version 12 in place does, and I didn't set default for javac. (Replace 2 highlighted instances of "java" below with "javac", according to [this](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-set-default-java-version-on-ubuntu-debian/).) **But I was able to install my problem app** -- Thank You again. It still gives me an error when I load it, but I'll see if the creators will help with that.

**sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk** [installs version 8]

**update-java-alternatives --list** [shows what versions are installed]

**sudo update-alternatives --config java** [allows to choose default]

[image]